# Error in Gitlab-CI pipeline with docker executor

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I´m facing the following problem inside my gitlab-ci pipeline:

```
`ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ce84c4ec94ce342dea27ba2d8f6d419e96c952442020da66e3d0062d22a37c35: no such file or directory`
```

The full log is:
`Running with gitlab-runner 10.5.0 (80b03db9)
  on gitlab-runner-small c9dfa23d
Using Docker executor with image node:6 ...
Starting service mysql:latest ...
Pulling docker image mysql:latest ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ce84c4ec94ce342dea27ba2d8f6d419e96c952442020da66e3d0062d22a37c35: no such file or directory
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image node:6 ...
Starting service mysql:latest ...
Pulling docker image mysql:latest ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ce84c4ec94ce342dea27ba2d8f6d419e96c952442020da66e3d0062d22a37c35: no such file or directory
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image node:6 ...
Starting service mysql:latest ...
Pulling docker image mysql:latest ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ce84c4ec94ce342dea27ba2d8f6d419e96c952442020da66e3d0062d22a37c35: no such file or directory
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ce84c4ec94ce342dea27ba2d8f6d419e96c952442020da66e3d0062d22a37c35: no such file or directory`

Any ideas how to solve?

The problem occurs since I deleted entrys of /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ because the disk of the system was full and this folder tooks 65% of the space.

Answer (score 0):

This corrupted your Docker storage. Completely remove (purge) Docker and re-install to see if this fixes the issue.